# SQL Server : Finding Max Value in Result Set

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, max

I have this code and I am having a hard time understanding why it is not working. I have searched for the solution, which is actually how my code ended up the way it is, but it just isn't working right... Any help would be appreciated.

What I am trying to do is select a single record for each client. The record that is selected should be the one that has the highest debtor balance. Instead, I am getting all debtors with their balances. Almost like it isn't grouping them back to the client...

```
SELECT  
    Debtorness.ClientName,
    Debtorness.DebtorName,
    MAX(Debtorness.DFB)
FROM
    (SELECT
         Clients.Name AS ClientName, 
         Debtors.Name AS DebtorName,
         (CalcAging.FundedBalance) AS DFB
     FROM   
         Clients 
     INNER JOIN
         CalcAging ON Clients.ClientKey = CalcAging.ClientKey 
     INNER JOIN
         Debtors ON CalcAging.DebtorKey = Debtors.DebtorKey 
     INNER JOIN
         CalcClient ON Clients.ClientKey = CalcClient.ClientKey
     WHERE
         Clients.Inactive='0'
     GROUP BY
         Clients.Name, Debtors.Name, CalcAging.FundedBalance, 
         CalcAging.MasterDebtorKey) AS Debtorness
GROUP BY 
    Debtorness.ClientName, Debtorness.DebtorName, Debtorness.DFB
ORDER BY 
    Debtorness.ClientName ASC
```

Example output of what I get:

```
Client1 | Debtor23 | Balance    
Client1 | Debtor47 | Balance
Client1 | Debtor14 | Balance  
Client2 | Debtor72 | Balance
Client2 | Debtor30 | Balance
```

Etc... For all clients. Again, I want to see all clients, but I just want the debtor with the highest balance for that client... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use **`row_number()`**

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT
        Clients.Name AS ClientName, 
        Debtors.Name AS DebtorName,
        CalcAging.FundedBalance AS DFB,
        ROW_NUMBER() over 
           (PARTITION BY Clients.Name ORDER BY CalcAging.FundedBalance DESC)  as rn
    FROM    
        Clients INNER JOIN
        CalcAging ON Clients.ClientKey = CalcAging.ClientKey INNER JOIN
        Debtors ON CalcAging.DebtorKey = Debtors.DebtorKey INNER JOIN
        CalcClient ON Clients.ClientKey = CalcClient.ClientKey
    WHERE
        Clients.Inactive='0'
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I have to look up what partition is doing, and row over means... Haha. Nevertheless, this works like a champ! Cheers!

Comment: remember accept this answer as correct if help you with your question.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution is to do a select over your current result. This is to **continue working** with what you **already have** and what you **already know** how to use.

the **result**:

```
    select clientname,debtorname,balance_column from (SELECT  Debtorness.ClientName,
    Debtorness.DebtorName,
    MAX(Debtorness.DFB)
FROM    (

SELECT
    Clients.Name AS ClientName, 
    Debtors.Name AS DebtorName,
    (CalcAging.FundedBalance) AS DFB
FROM    
    Clients INNER JOIN
    CalcAging ON Clients.ClientKey = CalcAging.ClientKey INNER JOIN
    Debtors ON CalcAging.DebtorKey = Debtors.DebtorKey INNER JOIN
    CalcClient ON Clients.ClientKey = CalcClient.ClientKey
WHERE
    Clients.Inactive='0'
 GROUP BY
    Clients.Name, Debtors.Name, CalcAging.FundedBalance, CalcAging.MasterDebtorKey
) AS Debtorness
GROUP BY Debtorness.ClientName, Debtorness.DebtorName, Debtorness.DFB
ORDER BY Debtorness.ClientName Asc) group by clientname having a.balance_column = Max(a.balance_column)
```

Comment: replace balance_column with your balance column

Comment: Had some problems getting this to go but I think I see where you're headed. I went with Juan's solution below, but thanks for the help mate!

Comment: Just trying to help, no problem